# Visual studio debbuger displays "true" as "0"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

A very weird case just happened to me - while using the debugger, it shows me that the value of some boolean variable is `true`, but when I print it (or do with it any other operation), it behaves as `0` (i.e. false).

What can I do to fix this bug? I'm afraid that this is environmental bug so publishing code-example will be meaningless. (a hidden, annoying memory management bug can't be the reason, right?), and in this context I want point out that it will surprise me to discover that my environment is not well-configured (I work on this project in this environment for more than a year).

So far I:

- Double-checked that the compiler doesn't make any optimization to the code, in my project properties.
- Tried to re-open visual studio and clean and re-build the project
- Searched on the web for solutions (didn't find any).
  I use visual studio 2010 and my programming language is C++

Regarding code-sharing requests:

I'm sorry but I can't publish the code (my bosses will not be happy to see it run in the web)....If you are able to give some ideas about possible reasons to the problem it will be great, and I will look for clues in the code myself, to check if these reasons really caused the problem. However, just to be clear, here are the few code-lines that struggle me:

```
    bool dir = getNode(location)->getNext()->getDirection(); //dir is displayed as "true" in the debbuger
    int toPush = (dir == 1) ? 1 : 0; //"toPush" is displayed as "0" in the debbugger
    cout<<dir<<endl; //both output 0.
    cout<<(dir == true)<<endl;
```

Following your request I'm attaching a screen-shot. Notice the value of "dir" that is deqplayed at the right-buttom of the screen as "true", and to the program output on the right, that ends with 0 (which correspond to the "cout<< dir" command).

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlv18.png)

Comment: is the variable initialized? What happens when you run it in Release?

Comment: Please post a small code example that recreates the issue.

Comment: Show your code, along with a screenshot that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: in release mode this variable is indeed true... I think that the value is initialized but I'm not 100% sure since the initialization is the tricky part and I'm currently debugging it. Even if its uninitialized, why the debugger and c++ will have different default values?

Comment: Even if the variable is uninitialized, it should show the same value unless it's interpreted in a different way (wrong format string?) or changed between the breakpoint and the initialization.

Comment: An uninitialized bool will have a value of false, true or FileNotFound.  The latter covers the other 254 possible values.

Comment: Why are you comparing dir to one?  Why not just: int toPush = dir ? 1 : 0;

Comment: can't be- first of all I eliminated the optimizations, and second I print the value and get "false"!!! (This is differ from the output in the release mode when the program indeed prints true....why???)

Comment: ironMensan- except the first line this code is meaningless and used to demonstrate the issue only, so I didn't care much about its design....

Comment: Your screen shot shows that dir has value 240 (the second to last line in the output). I would start there.

Comment: @user515430, Watch 1 windows shows that `dir` is type of `bool` and it's value is `true`!

Also don't trust to 240. I think this output was gotten from `24` (from previous output) + `0` (output of `dir` value)

Comment: @Bartolinio, try to find preprocessor macro definition. Maybe things are not what we are think. For example `cout` isn't classical `cout` from `iostream` header, but something weird.  I really can't help very much. Also try to create simple project from one file and check if boolean variables will have the same behaviour. I think the problem is in your project but not in compiler or IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `==` operator to test a `bool` value for truth.  Any non-zero value is true.  You have two `cout` lines and the last two lines in the console window say 240 and 0.  I wrote this to demonstrate what I think is happening:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static bool getDirection()
{
    union forceBoolValue
    {
        unsigned int iValue;
        bool bValue;
    };
    forceBoolValue retValue;
    retValue.iValue = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    return retValue.bValue;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    bool dir = getDirection();  //dir is now 255*, which is non-zero and therefore "true"
    int toPush = (dir == 1) ? 1 : 0;  //dir may be true but it is not one, so toPush is 0
    int toPush2 = dir ? 1 : 0;  //dir is true, so toPush2 is 1
    cout << "Dir: " << dir << endl;
    cout << "toPush: " << toPush << endl;
    cout << "toPush2: " << toPush2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

A similar thing happens with `dir == true` where it is probably again testing for the value of one.  I have no idea why `dir` is getting an unusual value in your code (240), but if you remove the comparisons and just test the value (as `toPush2` above) it should fix the issue.

I know you said the `toPush` line is just to demonstrate the issue, but are you doing comparisons in any of your real code?  If so, remove them.

*`dir` might not be 255, depends on the size of `bool` in your environment.

Comment: Very interesting point of view. But explain me, why return value of `getDirection()` isn't converted into bool type value (`true` or `false`)?

Comment: @GeorgeGaál I used a union to allow me to write the bits directly.  After that it is just copying the `bool` so there is no need to convert.  I had to jump through some hoops to force the issue, I'm not sure how it could happen unintentionally.